# How do I do a MySQL JOIN on conditions based on mathematical operations across two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in a CRM application that I am trying to build.

"Contacts" Table:

| id | Name | ContactFrequency (in days) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 7 |
| 2 | Pete | 30 |

"Events" Table:

| id | Contacts_id | Description | Unix_Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Sent John an email | 1609667504 |
| 2 | 1 | Gave John a call | 1609645455 |
| 1 | 2 | Sent Pete a letterl | 1609666755 |

The "ContactFrequency" is how often I should call that client to stay in touch. Each entry in Events is a call log with a UNIX timestamp. I want to generate a list of clients who need to be called in the next X number of days (or whose next contacts have already passed and are overdue), such as the following (timestamps are completely arbitrary in my examples):

| Client | Next Contact Due on (Timestamp)(Ordered by this column) |
| --- | --- |
| Pete | 1609645352 |
| John | 1609634342 |

How would I do this with a query? I can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formally:

```
SELECT Contacts.Name Client, 
       COALESCE(FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(Events.Unix_Timestamp)) + INTERVAL Contacts.ContactFrequency DAY, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) NextContactDueOn
FROM Contacts
LEFT JOIN Events ON Contacts.id = Events.Contacts_id
GROUP BY Client
ORDER BY NextContactDueOn DESC
```